# Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)

Tags: jquery, safari, mousewheel, scrolltop

I've some really strange bug with scrollTop() in Safari.

Here it is: http://miceclub.ru/ (grounds list on the map).

I'm using jquery scrollTop() function and mousewheel plugin.

I use: `$('.groundsListElements').scrollTop(currScrollTop);`

I've checked graph (currScrollTop on X and time on Y) - it's ok..

Has anybody had same problems?

**Here is a [video of the problem](http://miceclub.ru/Screen_Recording_5.mov).**

Comment: What, exactly, is not working in Safari? And in which browsers _does_ it work?

Comment: What's the issue? The only issue I see is that scrolling is somewhat jerky.

Comment: It works good in Chrome and FireFox (I'm using macOS)

Comment: I don't know why, but it changes parent div position (top).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the mousewheel plugin. When I run it in Safari (in Windows) and Chrome, the velocity never goes above 1 ([demo](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos)). I never noticed this problem with this plugin before.

So maybe in your code, multiple the value by a number if it is exactly equal to 1, that way Safari will scroll the window a bit faster.

---

Update: Actually there are a [few issues](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/issues) in the github repository about the velocity being off.

Comment: No! I've tested mousewheel plugin.. You can see that it change parent div position.. Why??

Comment: I want to say that problem isn't in scroll speed.

Comment: Well I have an issue in Chrome and Safari when I use the mousewheel inside the `groundsListElements` box. I'm not sure what issue you are having with the scrollTop. Can you post a screencast?

Comment: Wow it doesn't do that at all in Safari for Windows. Maybe try changing the `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` for the `.groundsList` css style.

Comment: I just made a quick screen cast (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1510510/temp/mice-club.avi) of what I see, in Safari for Windows... I noticed I don't have the three extra buttons to the right. I guess I need to be logged in? And if you turn the sound up, you'll hear how much I'm using the mousewheel to get the window to scroll. Honestly, I have no idea why there are such big differences in what we are seeing.

Comment: thanks! yep... it's problem with a speed - i'll fix it in a few days - it's simple.. but problem from my screen recording breaks my brain.. really..

Comment: Hiya, I don't think I can do anything else to help you solve this problem. So I'll tell you what, I'll add a bounty to get others to pay more attention ;)

Comment: Not reproduced on Windows 7 with Safari 5. I tested without the mousewheel code and changing .groundsListElements overflow to auto,  no problem either. Is the plugin only used to get the colored scrollbar ?